# Scalatest check division by 0 (exception)

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

I have simple Scala divide function like:

```
class ScalaFunction {
  /**
   * This is simple mathematics division function. Example: numerator = 20 and denominator = 4 equals 5 (result).
   * @param numerator also called dividend
   * @param denominator also called divisor
   * @return called quotient and it calculates how many times can we divide numerator by denominator
   */
  def divide(numerator: Double, denominator: Double): Double = denominator / numerator
}
```

Obviuosly `denominator` and `numerator` are switched. I want to write unit test with scalatest framework with `org.scalatest.WordSpecLike`style and DSL `org.scalatest.MustMatchers`. At the end Scala Spec class should look like:

```
class ScalaFunctionSpec extends WordSpecLike with MustMatchers {
  "A division function" when {
    val scalaFunction = new ScalaFunction()
    "divide 7 by 0" must {
      "result in exception or infinity" in {
        // how to check for infinity or division by 0?
        // scalaFunction.divide(7, 0) must equal(?inf?)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to check/test infinity/division by 0 in scalatest framework?

Thanks!

Best

Comment: If you just want to compare against `Infinity`, you can use [`Double.PositiveInfinity`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Double$). In the case of floating-point division by zero, you won't get an exception. You'll get `/ by zero` `ArithmeticException` when dividing integers by 0.

Answer (score 2):

For exceptions you generally use `intercept`. This says "I expect the function to throw a specific exception in the given scenario". In short, test will pass if the exception is thrown.

```
scenario("whatever") {
  val err = intercept[ArithmeticException] {
    callTheFunctionWithTheException
  }
  err.getMessage shouldEqual "somemessage"
}
```

Comment: intercept actually returns the exception so one can test for additional properties if one wants to.